# How to implment google map Api on both iOS 5.1 and iOS 6.0 + in the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I need to implement Google Maps API on iOS5.1, iOS6 and later.

I have used the Google map SDK 1.5 and google map work fine on iOS 6.0 and later. But app crash when run on the iOS 5.1.

After that I have implement the Google Map SDK 1.4.3 in the application. Now the application works fine on iOS 6.0 and later.

But, App crashes when I run on the iOS 5.1.

I need to implement google maps api on iOS5.1 and iOS6 later.

So ,Please help me to implement Google map API for both iOS 5.1 and iOS 6.0+ in the application.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the latest version: [1.7.2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start?hl=ru#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios) ?

Comment: How does it crash in 5.1, when you use SDK 1.4?

Comment: yes we have used the google map SDk 1.4.3 and after implemet that sdk application still crash in ios 5.1.